# Finding equation of tangent lines at a point to the ellipse : confusion on passing point

Tags: algebra-precalculus, conic-sections, tangent-line

This is the question,

**Equation of the tangent at the point (3, -1) to the ellipse $2x^2 + 9y^2 = 3$ is**

**Solution**

[image]

my question is, shouldn't the tangent pass through the point given?

one of the option was $2x + 3y = 3$

And what if the question was like

**Equation of the tangent from the point (3, -1) to the ellipse $2x^2 + 9y^2 = 3$ is**

the only change is **from the point** can I still use this formula? and should the points satisfy the tangent in this case also?

Comment: To follow the approach, does $(3,-1)$ have to be on the ellipse $2x^2+9y^2=3$?

Comment: The point doesn't satisfy the curve so it is not on the curve.

Comment: “Tangent at the point” means the point is on the ellipse $s=0,$ and the tangent then would be $s_1=0$ as you try to do. It really gives you the polar of the point wrt the ellipse.   Since the point is not on the ellipse “from the point” probably was meant and that would usually mean _the_ two tangents from a point outside the ellipse to the ellipse and they are given by $s_1^2-s \cdot s_{11}=0.$

Comment: So can I say when we have `tangent at the point (3, -1)` the point will not pass through the tangent and we can `use s=0` (above formula ) but when we have "tangent from the point (3, -1) " then the tangent will pass through the point and we can find the tangent by the `traditional method of differentiating`?

Comment: No, I'm saying the problem is formulated wrong. What you could do was calculate the polar as you do, and intersect the polar line with the ellipse, then you do get two points on the ellipse whose tangents at those points will go through $(3,-1).$

Comment: Since the point $(3,-1)$ is exterior to the ellipse, it should be two tangents. These are approximately  $\dfrac{y+1}{x-3}=-0.13 \text{ and} -0.67$. Any other distinct thing about it is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the stardard form of the ellipse equation:

$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$
Suppose the tangent line touches the ellipse at point $B(x_1,y_1)$. First, we find the slope $k$ for the tangent line by taking the derivative of the ellipse equation,

$$\frac{2x_1}{a^2}+\frac{2y_1}{b^2} y'=0\Longrightarrow y'=k=-\frac{b^2x_1}{a^2y_1}$$

then we can get the equation for the tangent line

$$y-y_1=-\frac{b^2x_1}{a^2y_1}(x-x_1)$$

Simplify and we get:

$$\frac{x_1}{a^2}x+\frac{y_1}{b^2}y=1\tag{1}$$

The point $A(3, -1)$ is outside the ellipse $2x^2 + 9y^2 = 3$. So there are two lines passing point $A$ and tangent to the ellipse at point $B$.

[image]

Note this step is **WRONG** in your solution! First, the tangent point $B$ is currently unknown for us, and we need to find its coordinate $(x_1, y_1)$ later.  We are given the point $A(3, -1)$ is on the tangent line, so we should plug in $x=3, y=-1$ and $a^2=\frac32, b^2=\frac13$ into eq.(1), hence we get

$$\frac{x_1}{\frac32}\cdot3+\frac{y_1}{\frac13}\cdot(-1)=1$$

Simplify and we get:

$$2x_1-3y_1=1\tag{2}$$

To find the find its coordinate $(x_1, y_1)$ for point $B$, we need another equation. Note that point $B$ is on the ellipse, hence

$$2x_1^2 + 9y_1^2 = 3\tag{3}$$

Combining (2) and (3), we get

$$(x_1, y_1)=(-\frac13, -\frac59)~~~~\text{or}~~~~(x_1, y_1)=(1, \frac13)$$

Namely, we get two tangent points on the ellipse,

$$B_1(-\frac13, -\frac59)~~~~\text{or}~~~~B_2(1, \frac13)$$

Finally, let's find these two tangent lines.

From point $A(3, -1)$ and point $B_1(-\frac13, -\frac59)$, we get tangent line $l_{AB_1}$

$$\boxed{y=-\frac2{15}x-\frac35}$$

From point $A(3, -1)$ and point $B_2(1, \frac13)$, we get tangent line $l_{AB_2}$

$$\boxed{y=-\frac23x+1}$$

Answer (score 1):

It seems you've been exposed to some part of [Joachimsthal's notation](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Generalization/JoachimsthalsNotations.shtml), in particular the $s_1=0,$ which is the tangent when the point is on the conic, but which more generally defines the polar of the point when the point is not on the conic.

There are more Joachimsthal notations. $s_1^2=s \cdot s_{11}$ is the one for your situation.

Let's factor $s_1^2-s \cdot s_{11},$ where the point is $(3,-1)$ and $s=0$ is your ellipse equation.

$$(2x^2+9y^2-3)(2(3)^2+9(-1)^2-3)-(2x\cdot 3+9y\cdot (-1)-3)^2)=\\3\cdot (3y+2x-3)(15y+2x+9)$$

As you can see, the two tangents fall right out.

[image: The two tangents to the ellipse from an external point]